# How to set India as a country in tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, google

I'm trying to use tor to test my website from UK. My website has custom content based on the geo-location of a user i.e; if a user opens from US IP he see's a US personalised content and if the user is from India he see's India specific content. SO while testing I tried to get only from US first by setting;

```
ExitNodes {us} StrictNodes 1
```

in the torrc file and it worked as expected and gave me access to the ip in US alone and the same reflected even in google analytics but when I did the same for India by setting

```
ExitNodes {in} StrictNodes 1
```

tor was still configured to India only but in google analytics I saw the ip was of US and not India.

So can someone tell me why google analytics is showing US for Indian based IP in tor. And how can I change it, so that google analytics shows India in its report.

Answer (score 0):

Although the procedure you have followed is exact, the Google Analytics might be using an exit node tracking mechanism, most of which are publicly available [here.](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/)

On encountering such IP nodes, Google Analytics is pointing back to its default location, US, as the source IP is unknown, thanks to Tor.

You should actually use a VPN(s) for an exact analysis.